# Why can't I use int to calculate bytes to gigabytes?

Tags: c#

I ran into some trouble when converting bytes to gigabytes in my current project. Initially I did this:

```
 long requiredDiskSpace = 5000000000000; // In bytes
 int gb = (int)requiredDiskSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
```

This calculation becomes 0. (Correct should be 4 656). Then I switched to the `decimal` type, like this:

```
 long requiredDiskSpace = 5000000000000; // In bytes
 decimal gb = requiredDiskSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
 int gbAsInt = (int)gb;
```

This calculation (correctly) makes `gbAsInt` 4 656.

Now, my question is simply; why? To me, the calculations look similar, as I'm not interested in any decimal numbers I don't understand why I can't just use int in the actual calculation.

Comment: Just a comment to you using `decimal`: It has nothing to do with `decimal`, but it works in this case because then you calculate the entire result before converting to `int`. The wrong part in the first example is that you convert `requiredDiskSpace` to `int` first (with loss), and then divide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is `(int)requiredDiskSpace`, the value `5000000000000` is way too big for an integer.

Comment: There are some days when you just don't feel very clever. This is one of them :) Thanks a lot, and cheers also for the interesting discussions in the other answers' comments. Accepting this as its short and to the point in answering the question why.

Answer (score 9):

You are trying to cast 5000000000000 to an integer. This will not work properly because that number is greater than `Int.MaxValue` So you should infact do:

```
int gb = (int)(requiredDiskSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);
```

Comment: IMO result you get with this is not correct: everytime you divide requiredDiskSpace by 1024, result is truncated. At the end Gigabytes calculated is wrong because you go throught four truncations. Do you agree? You could use int gb = (int)(requiredDiskSpace / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024));

Comment: @Marko: This is right if you are using the fractions at the end, but the fractions you loose are a long way down the chain, and they have no effect on the integer part of the later calculations.

Comment: Tested and proven false,,, sorry @Marco

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is `(int)` there. You are casting your `long` to `int` that way. But 5000000000000 cannot fit in a 32-bit integer so you end up with a completely different number between −2<sup>31</sup> and 2<sup>31</sup>. Dividing that by 1073741824 then yields 0.

I suspect you just wanted the result to be casted to `int`:

```
int gb = (int)(requiredDiskSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);
```

Comment: IMO result you get with this is not correct: everytime you divide requiredDiskSpace by 1024, result is truncated. At the end Gigabytes calculated is wrong because you go throught four truncations. Do you agree? You could use `int gb = (int)(requiredDiskSpace / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024));`

Comment: You're off by at most a GiB. In those size ranges that likely doesn't really matter, though.

Comment: In fact in my answer I used double :) But OP is using int, so it's not your fault :)

Comment: With `double` for the calculation you probably want the ceiling or rounded value if you need an `int` in the end. But With the pure int calculation you just add `1` and be most likely correct (with exactly one exception).

Comment: @Joey: I think adding 1 will (nearly) always make the result *incorrect*. Can you elaborate how you came to your conclusion?

Comment: Because of truncation you *under* estimate the value consistently. The worst case would be 1 GiB − 1 which would come up as 0 GiB. Essentially you have an error of *requiredDiskSpace* mod 1 GiB. Generally I'd say when communicating how much of a resource is used (such as disk space required) it's better to *over* estimate instead . Adding 1 solves this almost correctly by always rounding up except when requiredDiskSpace is an exact number of gibibytes in which case it's one too many.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is your cast. If you use parenthesis, it will work correctly:

```
(int)(requiredDiskSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
```

What happens in your code is this:

1. 5000000000000 is cast to an int, resulting in 658067456 because of integer overflow.
2. 658067456 is divided by 1024 resulting in 642644
3. 642644 is divided by 1024 resulting in 627.58203125. As all operations are taking place on ints, the result really is 627 as decimals are stripped away.
4. 627 is divided by 1024 resulting in 0.6123.. Again, decimals are stripped away and you end up with **0**

Comment: IMO result you get with this is not correct: everytime you divide `requiredDiskSpace` by 1024, result is truncated. At the end Gigabytes calculated is wrong because you go throught four truncations. Do you agree? You could use `int gb = (int)(requiredDiskSpace / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024));`

Comment: @Marco: I guess you are right, but as the result is an `int` anyway, that most likely isn't a problem. Additionally, I am not sure, whether or not the compiler optimizes this to one operation `requiredDiskSpace / 1073741824`.

Comment: @Marco: Your alternate proposal should be `requiredDiskSpace /` instead of `requiredDiskSpace *`

Comment: Well, my suggested formula uses just one approximation and only at the end, so it "could" be better. I don't know if compiler optimizes your formula: if so you're correct :)

Comment: @Marco: I think there is not a single case, where it makes a difference. Try to come up with one. I did and couldn't find one. The reason is, that there is no rounding involved. The decimals are simply stripped away. Example `1073741823` will yield 0 in both cases. `1073741824` will yield 1 in both cases and `1073741825` will also yield 1 in both cases.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: You are right. ReSharper will warn you on "possible loss of fraction" if you try to convert the result to a `double` instead of `int`, because you will loose the fractions in the end calculation, but if you convert the end result to `int`, ReSharper  does not warn you, because you are not using the lost fractions anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Cast after calculation:

```
    long requiredDiskSpace = 5000000000000; // In bytes
    int gb = (int)(requiredDiskSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);
```

When you cast immediately to int you lose value.

Comment: IMO result you get with this is not correct: everytime you divide requiredDiskSpace by 1024, result is truncated. At the end Gigabytes calculated is wrong because you go throught four truncations. Do you agree? You could use int gb = (int)(requiredDiskSpace / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024));

Answer (score 2):

You are casting the byte value to an `int`, which is not able to hold such a big number.

```
long test = 5000000000000;
int value = (int)test; // value = 658067456
```

Dividing this value three times by 1024 will result in `627 / 1024` which equals (in integer arithmetic) `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you use integer division, result is truncated to be an integer everytime.
So you have zero in first attempt, even because 5000000000000 is too big to be stored in an int var.
You should use

```
double gb = 1.0d * requiredDiskSpace / (1024 * 1024 * 1024);
```

Comment: If you are really concerned about keeping all the fractions, you should use `decimal` instead of `double`. With `double` you loose low level fractions along the way. At the end, using `decimal` you will get `4656.612873077392578125`, but using `double` you will get `4656.6128730773926`.